# Eevee NaN/White pixels

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I have a problem with some render in Eevee, sometimes I get strange artifacts like white pixels.
I don't know what is the cause, it doesn't appear in all renders, but it does it with particularly shiny materials in combination with normal map or bump.
This effect get worse considerably with Camera DoF or Bloom.
Here is an example:
[image: Eevee render without Camera DoF]
[image: Eevee render with DoF]
I've prepared a simple file to reproduce the issue:
[image: sample file to reproduce the problem]
[image]

Here are material nodes that cause the problem (same as example file):
[image: material node displacement]
[image: material node bump]

And the World settings is the default one, but got same effect even with HDRI map:
[image: world settings]

Comment: Hello, please post a screenshot of your node tree and the world settings

Comment: You shouldn't be plugging values directly into material output/displacement.  The odds are also good that you shouldn't be using that much displacement (probably 0-0.01 range, not 0-1 range.)  Put a displacement node before the output node, tune its scale, and see if that improves your situation.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, I'll try. But as you can see I've also tried another solution (the second shader nodes image) passing data as Bump instead of Displacement but the result is the same. I'll let you know if something changes following your suggestion

Comment: I've tried placing a Displacement node before output but it doesn't solve the problem. If I reduce the displacement scale, white pixels increase... and the patttern fade.